# Plain good sense

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am not a native speaker and i want to translate an article.. Can you please tell me What does " she is full of plain good sense" mean? Is plain here an adjective?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but [oxforddictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plain) identifies the *specific* usage in your example as an ***adverb*** *(informal, as submodifier)*, ***Used for emphasis*** - their usage example being *perhaps the youth was just plain stupid*. Perhaps that's because in their example it's modifying ***stupid***, which is definitely an adjective itself - but in practice I think it would be a bit punctilious to say your ***plain*** is an ***adjective*** simply because ***good sense*** is a ***noun***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "plain good sense" means something like "basic, simple rational thought"  in the praiseworthy sense that it does not involve any sort of casuistry or any pseudo-sophistication.

I would understand **plain** as an adjective modifying the noun phrase "good sense".

Comment: I'd say it's an "adjective" too. But per my comment above, might OxfordDictionary be calling it an "adverb" because *their* example happens to have it modifying another adjective *(**stupid**, as opposed to **good sense** here)*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Right, "stupid" there's an adjective alone.

Comment: Yes, but let's not call "good sense" a noun phrase.  A noun phrase can have a determiner, but what "plain" modifies here cannot have a determiner.  It's an N-bar (written N'), not a NP.

Comment: @GregLee Sorry, Greg, you've lost me.  Is "home cooking" a noun phrase or an N-bar?

Comment: And do you mean that "good sense" can *never* have a determiner? Or only when **plain** is modifying it?

Comment: @TRomano, Neither one. "Home cooking" is a noun compound.  Since it is a noun, it can be used as a NP sometimes, or an N-bar sometimes, like any other noun.  We'd have to consider specific examples.

Comment: @GregLee    So it's the fact that **plain** is modifying **good sense** that turns it into a N-bar?

Comment: @TRomano, No, I mean that in "plain good sense", we cannot add a determiner to "good sense".  *"plain the good sense"

Comment: @GregLee  So "chance" in "fat chance" is an N-bar? or "dumb luck" is an N-bar in "sheer dumb luck"?

Comment: @TRomano, "fat chance" is a noun, but like other nouns, it can be used as an N-bar.

Comment: @GregLee: I don't understand how "fat chance" is a noun. Do nouns with modifiers reduce to 'noun'?

Comment: @TRomano, I'm not sure it's a noun.  Maybe it's a sentence.  I take back what I said.

Comment: @GregLee: So these categorizations are driven by the semantics of the utterance?

Comment: @TRomano, I do not know a discovery procedure for syntactic category.

Answer (score 0):

Plain is a **adverb** meaning *"in a plain manner : **without** obscurity or ambiguity"*, that is clearly or unequivocally. From Merriam Webster dictionary.

Definition of plain (Entry 3 of 5): https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plain

`she is full of plain good sense`

Comment: Can you explain the whole phrase to me please?

Comment: @RanaGhamdi Explanation: Author is trying convey that she has unequivocally or clearly a good sense.

Comment: It's not an adverb, though there is an adverb "plainly" with a related meaning: "She is plainly full of good sense."